# Muting audio source from within an html iframe possibly using JS

Tags: javascript, html, audio, mute

I am working on a gallery page with quite a few external HTML pages embedded using iframe, however, some of these external pages have audio embedded into them which I would like to mute.

Here is a sample code for the HTML files

**gallery.html**

```
<div id="pages">
    <iframe id="embed" src="https://xyz.com/page1.html"></iframe>
    <iframe id="embed" src="https://sdf.com/page2.html"></iframe>
</div>
```

**page1.html**

```
<html>
  <head>
     <!-- head stuff-->
  </head>
  <body>
     <audio autoplay>
       <source src="http://audio.url/somefile.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
       <source src="http://audio.url/somefile.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
       Your browser does not support the audio tag.
     </audio>
     <!--some more body content>
  <body>
 </html>
```

Also, since I'm dealing with multiple external pages, the audio tags mostly might not have ids attached to them. This makes `document.getElementById()` a non-reliable option. I've experimented with `document.getElementsByTagName("input")` but couldn't quite get the audio muted. Can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: I've also tried: `document.getElementsByTagName("audio").muted = true;` but this method also seems to fail.

Comment: Why not set the controls on the audio, because trying to locate an element on the other side of an iframe with vanilla JS is difficult if it doesn't have an id.

Answer (score -1):

Since these pages are being served up from different domains you will not be able to access the HTML within the iframe due to same origin policy.